# Several Include objects, how reference them?

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to simulate a TabHost, I am programming for Android 2.3.3 using Eclipse.
So, I have buttons that are intended to make visible or not the layout below them. Suppose I have 3 buttons, click B1 make visible Layout L1 and invisible the L2 and L3 layouts, and so for.
My problem is, how reference the layouts if they are viewed by using the include tag??
In the Properties Panel of Eclipse I give them Id's, for example copy1 for L1 and so for.
Let me do another question, can they manage data independently? I mean, the user could store data in L1, L2 and L3 without overwriting?

Answer (score 0):

My questions were answered in this page http://www.coboltforge.com/2012/05/tech-stuff-layout/
great contribution.
This page is also important http://gibby.net.au/android-accessing-objects-within/.

And I self answered the question if those copies behaves independently, they user enter and store data in the views L1, L2 and L3. I tested and fortunately they behave separately :-)